# Is the database-per-service pattern recommended in cloud-db-services?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, architecture, microservices

I have questions about the database-per-service pattern in microservices.

Suppose I have two services: one for posts and the other for comments. These two services need to have their own DB. DB is MongoDB. I have set a schema and there is an objectid called post in the comments schema (after all, it is necessary to know which post is commented on  ) and here I am showing the comments database as a "ref". This is also possible in MongoDB. There is something called "Cross database populate":

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#cross-db-populate

But let's say my posts db crashed and it doesn't work. Is there any problem? After all, a core of the microservice architecture is that each service can run independently. But now, if a dependency has been created  would that be a problem? Because i think they can get the entries from an other chrashed-DB and that is not cached or something like this... That would be meaning, that every service is not independent or do i misunderstand that?

In the other hand is that really necessary to work with the "database-per-service" pattern if your database is a cloud-db-service like mongodb atlas? I mean you can scale it... I think every service can have the same connection string if you use a cloud-db-service like mongodb atlas or is that a bad idea? (Maybe a bad idea in relation to the independency of every service?)

Comment: When you have two services, their database should not reference each other's databases. That defeats the purpose of having microservices which should be loosely coupled. You may couple your services loosely by sending post-id (which is not a database ID, but the identification of the aggregate object "Post") which comments service can use to associate comments with a post.

Answer (score 0):

> After all, a core of the microservice architecture is that each service can run independently

Yes, basically the idea behind the microservice architecture style is to split the application into services which are loosely coupled and independently deployable.

> That would be meaning, that every service is not independent or do i misunderstand that?

Yes, this introduces dependency between services, [shared database](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/shared-database.html) is usually considered an anti-pattern or at least smell in microservice architecture (there are a lot of things which could go wrong here and database failure is not the only one).

> I think every service can have the same connection string if you use a cloud-db-service like mongodb atlas or is that a bad idea?

Yes it is a bad one. Services should not know anything about each other databases and their internal structure.

Just store some kind of external id of the post in the comment, so they are loosely coupled and that's it, for everything else use async communication via some message bus.

P.S. Note that the goal of microservice architecture is not to split every domain entity into a separate service and produce as many services as possible, in some cases it does make sense to combine related services into one (have seen several instances of such when highly cohesive data/services were first split and then brought back together), though probably not in this particular case.